# how to make all long-duration skactions work at the same time not one after one

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction, sknode

I am working on sprite kit and now what I want to do is that I am using a for loop and check how many sknodes there are in an array and make every sknode in the array do an skaction which remains a very long time - probably an hour. However, every time I do this, it just does the first skaction to the first sknode but not the rest of the sknodes. I think it is because it is waiting for the first one to complete and then jump to the second one in for loop. So how can I do to make them perform action at the same time?

Comment: post your code. know your enemy: you can run skaction independently, or sequence them in a sequence action. The same action can only be run on a single node, if you want to reuse the action, you have to copy it, ie: [myAction copy] wherever you use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
for node in nodes {
    let action1 = SKAction()
    let action2 = SKAction()
    let action3 = SKAction()
    let group = SKAction.group([action1,action2,action3])

    node.removeActionForKey("group")
    node.runAction(group, withKey: "group")
}
```

You should use `group:` method of `SKAction` to make actions run simultaneously, and after that you add them to execution queue by calling `runAction:` method. Note that if you have some action that is already running, execution won't start until that previous action is completed, so you have to remove that action by calling `removeActionForKey:` method

Comment: Thank you for your code, I think it should work but I don't  why it doesn't. I put all skactions in an array every time it loops. Then after the loop, I run skaction with group so that it can work simultaneously. But it only run the first action. i don't know why.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have solved my problem! But i have one strange issue. I believe that it is because I ran the group of skactions. Because when I comment that line, the bug won't show. The bug is that every time my app becomes active. I will do those actions, right? But when i tried to remove one of the SKNode which is performing action (I have one gesture to delete SKNode). I always got NSRangeException which is about for loop maybe. But I don't know where is wrong because in that code, there is no for loop causing the problem.

Comment: @zh_Vincent When you remove the node, try calling `node.removeAllActions()` before calling `node.removeFromParent()`

Comment: I think it doesn't matter because I can remove node with actions being performed before. But every after calling the method when app becomes active. It will crash.